# Set from e-mail address for new user registration only?

Tags: users

In Drupal 7, it's quite easy to change the body of the emails here:

```
/admin/config/people/accounts
```

However, it has no place to set the "from" email address. I'm getting lots of spam signups and want the from email address to be "noreply@mysite.com", so as to make any responses get disgarded.

Any idea how to do this? Or even what email address is set for these emails?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hook_mail_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to change the "from" email address of any email sent out from your site. Your code would look something like...

```
function yourmodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $message['from'] = $message['headers']['From'] = '"Full Name" <noreply@mysite.com>';
}
```

Also, keep in mind that just setting the "from" address may not have the desired results in all email clients (see the [discussion on the Drupal issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/656472)). You might also need to set "sender", "errors-to" and "reply-to" based on your requirements. Those values are in the "header" of the `$message` variable from the code sample above.

Answer (score 0):

First off... if you haven't already, take a look at:

[captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) and [reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)

> A CAPTCHA is a challenge-response test most often placed within web
>   forms to determine whether the user is human. The purpose of CAPTCHA
>   is to block form submissions by spambots, which are automated scripts
>   that post spam content everywhere they can. The CAPTCHA module
>   provides this feature to virtually any user facing web form on a
>   Drupal site.
>
> Uses the reCAPTCHA web service to improve the CAPTCHA system and
>   protect email addresses.

plus a dozen or more other spam protection modules. I found these are very effective at elminating the bots.

Also, take a look at [User IP Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/uiplog)

> User IP Log is a simple module that logs the IP address of users on
>   login event to table {uiplog}.

with this you can block the ip addresses of known spammers - it takes some time but in the long run has a profound effect.

You could also set the default email address for the site to noreply@site.com which will make all system emails appear from that address, and then use something like [Contact Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_forms) which if memory serves will allow you to set the sender address for different contact forms.